# what does "suit up" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, vocabulary, word-meaning, phrases

I am reading the script of a TV series "How I Met Your Mother"

The script has this sentence:

> Hey, you want to do somethin' tonight? Okay, meet me at the bar in 15 minutes.
>   And suit up! Where's your suit? Just once, when I say suit up, I wish you'd put on a suit.

What does "suit up" means please?

I tried to use a dictionary but it seems it is not a formal phrase.

Comment: See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/suit-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that context, "How I Met Your Mother", Barney literally and specifically means put on a suit, with a jacket and tie.

In other contexts, it means 'prepare for an activity by putting on the appropriate clothes, uniform or equipment.'

Comment: So it seems you have watched this series. Do you suggest me to watch it in order to  learn more english? and is it a funny tv series like _Friends_ or not ?

Comment: Sure, it's a pretty good show.  It can be very witty at times so if you're learning English, the captions will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct, but the expression usually has a sense of specialized clothing that has a protective purpose.

For example, a diver might suit up with a wetsuit, or an astronaut would suit up with a space suit.

Answer (score 1):

[it means](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/suit-up) : to get ready for an activity by putting on a uniform or special clothes.

> Suit up, and we go.